# Linux sort vs programming

Tags: linux, sorting

I'm trying to grasp why my software (golang) is 350 times slower compared to linux sort command? I was sorting UTF-8 text file around 13.000.000 lines (4 - 20 bytes long).

code sample from my function (if checkDupl false append to newArray):

```
func checkDupl(in []byte) bool {
    for i := range newArray {
        if bytes.Equal(in, newArray[i]) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

This code finished around 25% over night.

This code finished in 8min:

```
  497  export LC_ALL=C
  498  time sort -us -o file_unique.txt file.txt
```

Comment: Without the rest of your code it's a bit hard to tell, but that *looks* like it's going to be part of an O(N^2) implementation. All other things being the same that will be several hundred thousand times slower for your input size than what `sort` will do.

Comment: @MichaelHomer The rest of the code is bare minimum. I can share it if you want. You are right about O(N^2). I assume sort is using some sort of algorithm instead of O(N^2)?

Comment: `sort(1)` is using merge sort which means that it's not only lightning fast, but it can also use more than one processor and can sort data larger than it can hold in memory. I'm not using golang but I'm pretty sure that it has some decent `sort` library function, though it won't hurt if you tried to write your own -- the [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)  algorithm is really not hard to grasp.

Comment: ... and merge sort is O(*n* log *n*) typical case (and worst case). Once the list is sorted, if duplicates haven’t already been dropped, filtering them is O(*n*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort -u` works by sorting the input, then iterating through and printing out each unique element. It can do that just by remembering which was the last thing it printed, and printing a new item whenever it changes.

Your code appears to be a linear search of the output array, so I assume it's part of a wider algorithm something like this:

```
for each X in input:
    if not checkDupl(X) then:
        append X to newArray
```

That means your `checkDupl` function runs once for every item in the input, and then the loop inside `checkDupl` runs once for every item in the output. In the worst case, the whole list is unique, so `checkDupl` looks at one item the first time, then two, then three, then four, .... That sequence adds up to n(n + 1) / 2, or 0.5n^2 + 0.5n. 13,000,000 squared dominates the 6.5 million of the other term, so we call that algorithm "quadratic time", or O(n^2). That's the worst case, and also an average case (but your best case, 13,000,000 identical lines, will be fairly quick).

There are many conventional sorting algorithms that work in O(n log n) time. [POSIX does not *require* `sort` to use one of those](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html), but all sensible implementations will do so. The log(n) term grows very slowly, so this will be much less than n^2. The printing is linear time, O(n), and can be ignored for the same reason as above.

---

Your program will take much longer to run than `sort` in all but the most trivial cases, for all but the most stupid of `sort`s. For your thirteen million items the difference could be hundreds of thousands of times (ignoring everything else about the programs).

You could implement a sorting algorithm and replicate `sort`'s approach, or use a library function. You could also use a data structure more suited to checking uniquity, like a hash table, rather than an array that requires a linear search. Most likely, it'll be better to use library functions than to try to roll everything yourself.